# Python: pairwise comparison between two lists: list a >= list b?

Tags: python, list, comparison

If I want to like to check if all the elements in a list

`a: [1 2 3 6]`

are greater than or equal to their corresponding elements in another list

`b: [0 2 3 5]`

If a[ i ] > b[ i ] for all *i*'s, then return true, otherwise false.
Is there a logical function for this? such as a>b? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean pairwise?  Ie a1 > b1, a2>b2 or a1>all b's

Comment: Yeah, Adam. Sorry about the confusion, i actually meant pairwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you actually want to compare every element in `a` against `b` you actually just need to check against the `max` of `b` so it will be an `0(n)` solution short circuiting if we find any element less than the max of b:

```
mx = max(b)
print(all(x >= mx for x in a))
```

For pairwise you can use enumerate:

```
print(all(x >= b[ind] for ind,x in enumerate(a)))
```

Or using hughbothwell's zip idea use itertools.zip:

```
from itertools import izip
print(all(x >= y for x,y  in izip(a,b)))
```

Or numpy:

```
print(np.greater_equal(a,b).all())

print(np.all(a >= b))
```

Comment: @C.Zeng, no worries , are you using numpy or normal python lists?

Comment: Thanks heaps. I am currently just using a normal list, and I am open to switching to numpy. I heard numpy is faster in a lot of cases, right?

Comment: @C.Zeng, you're welcome. Yes for large data numpy would be very efficient.

Answer (score 8):

You could just do

```
all(x >= y for x,y in zip(a,b))
```

which has the advantage of short-circuit evaluation: if it finds any `x < y` it returns `False` immediately.

Comment: Gonna vote this one up because it doesn't presume anything about numpy and requires no imports.

Answer (score 1):

You can write out an explicit for loop, or you can do an inline double loop and an all as shown below with the interpreter.

```
>>> a = {1,2,3,4}
>>> b = {2,3,4,5}
>>> lst = [x>y for x in a for y in b]
>>> lst
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, True, False,False]
>>> all(bool==True for bool in lst)
False
```

Comment: `all(x>y for x in a for y in b)` will do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use numpy, you can do this with a logic function (and it's much faster than pure python list comparisons)

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> a=array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b=array([3,0,3,1,2])
>>> a > b
array([False,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

Comment: I don't think you should assume the use of numpy. See my idea below.

Comment: I only put this answer because OP asked about using the ">" operator.  I upvoted another answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Do I win the code-golf?

```
a=[1,3,8,6]
b=[0,2,3,5]

print all(map(cmp,a,b))
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham How so..?

Comment: try `all(map(cmp, [1],[1]))`, the correct answer is True

Comment: Really? I thought the OP clarified: *If each element in a is greater than each element in b, then return True, other wise false.*

Comment: *are greater than or equal to elements in another list* hence the green tick . nice resurrecting cmp though cannot remember the last time I saw it used ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Haha. Well... It seems the OP contradicted himself. He says that at first, but his second statement means something else. Then he used `such as a>b?` to describe his intent. Oh well.. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 6]
b = [0, 2, 3, 5]

def check_lists(a, b):
    result = []

    for i in range(len(a)):
        result.append(a[i] >= b[i])

    return result

print check_lists(a, b)
```